# How to set the DB ConnectionStringSettings in Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection

Studio 2010 C# application accessing LUW DBs.  I am receiving an error when building my DB Conncetion settings in the code behind file rather than using the web.config.  We have a third party product where passwords are stored and retrieved.

The old web.config file method currently establishs DB connection as follows:

In the web.config file:

```
<add name="myDBConnect" connectionString="Database=mydbname;User    
ID=myuserid;Password=abcxyz" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2"/>
```

In the code behind file the following is executed to open the DB connection:

```
ConnectionStringSettings settings = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBConnect"];
ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
        if ((settings != null))
        {
            foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cs in settings)
            {
                returnValue = cs.ProviderName;
            }
        }
```

The above logic works fine - but I am now trying to dynamically build the connection string after retrieving the appropriate password from our third party product as follows:

(Note: connPW is the password retrieved from thrid party product)

```
ConnectionStringSettings settings = "Database=" + mydbname + ";User ID=" + myuserid + ";Password=" + connPW + " providerName=IBM.Data.DB2";
```

This line of code receives the following error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Configuration.ConnctionStringSettings'

Can someone please suggest how I can get past this error when defining settings. Thanks

Comment: you can do it manually for sure

Comment: Why use `ConnectionStringSettings`? Doesn't the connection string itself suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving that error to you because you are settings a String object equal to a ConnectionStringSettings object, of course. If you would like to use `ConnectionStringSettings`, you just need to use the `ConnectionStringSettings(string name, string connectionString, string providerName)` constructor.

```
ConnectionStringSettings settings = new ConnectionStringSettings("name", "Database=" + mydbname + ";User ID=" + myuserid + ";Password=" + connPW, "IBM.Data.DB2");
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I will research and move forward.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `ConnectionStringSettings`; you should connect to the string directly.

You should also use `DbConnectionStringBuilder` fix fix the injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString = "your connection string";
```

IF you the above code the system will throw an error " Configuration is Read Only" since the configuration is Read Only
we can do it by this method

```
  var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"];
    var Reset = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField(
                  "_bReadOnly", 
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    Reset .SetValue(settings, false);
    settings.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Something";
```